# Replace a string value from json file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to replace the value of "version" from the below json file with a variable I defined already in Jenkins pipeline.

```
{
  "name": "new-relic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Tools",
  "summary": "A brief module description",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "source": "https://github.com/DI-Test/puppet-newrelic",
  "dependencies": [

  ],
  "operatingsystem_support": [
    "RedHat based Linux"
  ],
  "requirements": [
    {
      "name": "puppet",
      "version_requirement": ">= 7.24 < 9.0.0"
    }
  ],
  "pdk-version": "3.0.0",
  "template-url": "pdk-default#3.0.0",
  "template-ref": "tags/3.0.0-0-g056e50d"
}
```

I tried with writeJson, writeFile. It all replace the file

```
writeJSON(  file: 'metadata.json',
                                            json: [
                                                version: "${puppet_module_version}-${BRANCH_NAME}",])
```

It replace all the json content and add only one string "version"

```
stage('Build Puppet Module Package') {    
                steps {
                    script {
                        def metadata = readJSON file: 'metadata.json'
                        env.puppet_module_name = metadata["name"]
                        env.puppet_module_version = metadata["version"]
                        container('puppet') {
                            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                                sh label: 'Build Puppet Module', script: 'pdk build --force'
                            } else {
                                 
                                Map attributes = readJSON(file: 'metadata.json')
                                attributes['version'] = "${puppet_module_version}-${BRANCH_NAME}"
                                writeJSON(file: 'metadata.json', json: attributes)
                                
                                sh label: 'Build Puppet Module', script: 'pdk build --force'
                                sh label:   'Display metadata.json',
                                    script: """
                                        cat metadata.json
                                    """
                            }
                            // // Build puppet module package using pdk
                            // sh (label: 'PDK Build Module', script: 'pdk build --force')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

jq is the right tool,install it in your environment.
For more details refe this link https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/e8979e269fb2fd7eae535019ad83781c

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that

```
stage('Build Puppet Module Package') {    
                steps {
                    script {
                        def metadata = readJSON file: 'metadata.json'
                        env.puppet_module_name = metadata["name"]
                        env.puppet_module_version = metadata["version"]
                        env.NEW_VERSION = "${puppet_module_version}-${BRANCH_NAME}" //using only for feature branch

                        container('puppet') {
                            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                                sh label: 'Build Puppet Module', script: 'pdk build --force'
                            } else {
                                 
                                def jsonFilePath = 'metadata.json' 
                                def newVersion = "${NEW_VERSION}"
                                def jsonContent = readFile(jsonFilePath)
                                jsonContent = jsonContent.replaceAll(/"version":\s*".*?"/, "\"version\": \"$newVersion\"")
                                writeFile file: jsonFilePath, text: jsonContent
                                sh label: 'Build Puppet Module', script: 'pdk build --force'
                                sh label:   'Display metadata.json',
                                    script: """
                                        cat metadata.json
                                    """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```